# Web application crashes on iPad and iPhone on device but not on debug (web inspector)

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, web-inspector

Its a highly weird situation but I have a problematic web application (no it is not the weird part). So basically its designed on ASP MVC Framework by using bs3 and responsive design and working nice on desktop.

My problem is; some edit pages are crashing on iOS devices and the weird part is when I try to trace the bug and connect the device to Web Inspector, it never crashes. When ever I remove the cable and try again, it crashes :S Did someone have any similar issue before?

Comment: When you say it crashes, are you saying that the site itself crashes right? Is this isolated to just say Safari or is is basically any browser on the iPad? I'd also recommend trying BrowserStack and seeing if it you can replicate the behavior through there. Setup the same configuration of an iPad and pull up your site. It might be browser related or something more.

Comment: Safari crashes and disapear from screen and it is just Safari. Thanks for the trick I am trying now.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this. I am having this problem now.

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a memory limitation on iPad when you have either numerous AJAX calls, numerous active download connections and/or numerous DOM manipulations/dynamic HTML.  I suggest you use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

to disable user interactions, reduce/consolidate AJAX calls, minify files, and use Chrome's performance Audit for other helpful tips.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. I tried all the options but it still persists. I think it is a problem of Safari on iOS7